# Why AWS aws_instance creates 2 instances instead of 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

In my Terraform I create an Instance with an elastic ip:

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}


resource "aws_instance" "myapp_staging" {
    ami=data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
    instance_type="t3a.micro"
    
    root_block_device {
        volume_size = 30
        volume_type = "gp3"
    }

    vpc_security_group_ids=[
      "XXXXXXXX"
    ]

    tags={
      Name="myapp_staging"
    }

    volume_tags = {
      Name="myapp_staging"
    }
}



resource "aws_eip" "myapp_staging_ip" {
  tags = {
    Environment="Staging"
    Client="Esupport"
    Type="IP"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = aws_instance.myapp_staging.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.myapp_staging_ip.id
}
```

But on EC-2 Console I see 2 AWS instances to be created instead of 1:

[image]

And I cannot understand why.

The Terraform plan creates another instance named this:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_eip.myapp_staging_ip will be created
  + resource "aws_eip" "myapp_staging_ip" {
      + allocation_id        = (known after apply)
      + association_id       = (known after apply)
      + carrier_ip           = (known after apply)
      + customer_owned_ip    = (known after apply)
      + domain               = (known after apply)
      + id                   = (known after apply)
      + instance             = (known after apply)
      + network_border_group = (known after apply)
      + network_interface    = (known after apply)
      + private_dns          = (known after apply)
      + private_ip           = (known after apply)
      + public_dns           = (known after apply)
      + public_ip            = (known after apply)
      + public_ipv4_pool     = (known after apply)
      + tags                 = {
          + "Environment" = "Staging"
          + "Type"        = "IP"
        }
      + tags_all             = {
          + "Environment" = "Staging"
          + "Type"        = "IP"
        }
      + vpc                  = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_eip_association.eip_assoc will be created
  + resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
      + allocation_id        = (known after apply)
      + id                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_id          = (known after apply)
      + network_interface_id = (known after apply)
      + private_ip_address   = (known after apply)
      + public_ip            = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_instance.myapp_staging will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "myapp_staging" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-0d940f23d527c3ab1"
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + associate_public_ip_address          = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone                    = (known after apply)
      + cpu_core_count                       = (known after apply)
      + cpu_threads_per_core                 = (known after apply)
      + disable_api_stop                     = (known after apply)
      + disable_api_termination              = (known after apply)
      + ebs_optimized                        = (known after apply)
      + get_password_data                    = false
      + host_id                              = (known after apply)
      + host_resource_group_arn              = (known after apply)
      + iam_instance_profile                 = (known after apply)
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = (known after apply)
      + instance_state                       = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                        = "t3a.micro"
      + ipv6_address_count                   = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses                       = (known after apply)
      + key_name                             = (known after apply)
      + monitoring                           = (known after apply)
      + outpost_arn                          = (known after apply)
      + password_data                        = (known after apply)
      + placement_group                      = (known after apply)
      + placement_partition_number           = (known after apply)
      + primary_network_interface_id         = (known after apply)
      + private_dns                          = (known after apply)
      + private_ip                           = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                           = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                            = (known after apply)
      + secondary_private_ips                = (known after apply)
      + security_groups                      = (known after apply)
      + source_dest_check                    = true
      + subnet_id                            = (known after apply)
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name" = "myapp_staging"
        }
      + tags_all                             = {
          + "Name" = "myapp_staging"
        }
      + tenancy                              = (known after apply)
      + user_data                            = (known after apply)
      + user_data_base64                     = (known after apply)
      + user_data_replace_on_change          = false
      + volume_tags                          = {
          + "Name" = "myapp_staging"
        }
      + vpc_security_group_ids               = [
          + "XXXXXXXXX",
        ]

      + root_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 30
          + volume_type           = "gp3"
        }
    }

  # module.ec2-instance.aws_instance.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "this" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-0785f49d3c3be2037"
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + associate_public_ip_address          = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone                    = (known after apply)
      + cpu_core_count                       = (known after apply)
      + cpu_threads_per_core                 = (known after apply)
      + disable_api_stop                     = (known after apply)
      + disable_api_termination              = (known after apply)
      + ebs_optimized                        = (known after apply)
      + get_password_data                    = false
      + host_id                              = (known after apply)
      + host_resource_group_arn              = (known after apply)
      + iam_instance_profile                 = (known after apply)
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = (known after apply)
      + instance_state                       = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                        = "t3.micro"
      + ipv6_address_count                   = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses                       = (known after apply)
      + key_name                             = (known after apply)
      + monitoring                           = (known after apply)
      + outpost_arn                          = (known after apply)
      + password_data                        = (known after apply)
      + placement_group                      = (known after apply)
      + placement_partition_number           = (known after apply)
      + primary_network_interface_id         = (known after apply)
      + private_dns                          = (known after apply)
      + private_ip                           = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                           = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                            = (known after apply)
      + secondary_private_ips                = (known after apply)
      + security_groups                      = (known after apply)
      + source_dest_check                    = true
      + subnet_id                            = (known after apply)
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name" = ""
        }
      + tags_all                             = {
          + "Name" = (known after apply)
        }
      + tenancy                              = (known after apply)
      + user_data                            = (known after apply)
      + user_data_base64                     = (known after apply)
      + user_data_replace_on_change          = false
      + volume_tags                          = {
          + "Name" = ""
        }
      + vpc_security_group_ids               = (known after apply)

      + credit_specification {}

      + enclave_options {
          + enabled = (known after apply)
        }

      + metadata_options {
          + http_endpoint               = "enabled"
          + http_put_response_hop_limit = 1
          + http_tokens                 = "optional"
          + instance_metadata_tags      = (known after apply)
        }

      + timeouts {}
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `aws_instance` resource in your Terraform code, that is creating one EC2 instance. You are also using a Terraform module, named `ec2-instance` which you failed to include in your question, but can be seen in the Terraform `plan` output, that is also creating one EC2 instance.